# Slow loading of images in my react project

Tags: reactjs, portfolio

I created a portfolio web site but my images are loading slowly I want all my images to load even before the page is loaded to provide a better user experience
here is my git repository url : https://github.com/Bala-Sai-Teja-Singh/PortFolio
here is my hosting url : https://bala-sai-teja-singh.github.io/PortFolio

I have tried using lazy load but it didn't give what i was expecting

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Use `eager` loading if you want your images to load immediately. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_loading.asp

Comment: Yes I used them but no use